# JSON en fragment no funciona

Tags: json, fragment

Necesito leer un Json en un fragment para añadir items a una lista. El código del fragment es el siguiente:

```
package com.example.mantenimiento;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.TableLayout;
    import android.widget.TableRow;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray; import com.google.gson.JsonElement; //import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*; import org.json.JSONArray; import org.json.JSONException; import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Tareas extends Fragment {
    private  ArrayList<String> cabeceras;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador_tareas;
    String SPREAD_SHEET_ID="1q7x1Nmf6yZtZFQfZ3FW4Od-ntlHv5XL4C-jTmdOc_wg";
    String ScriptTareas="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxtkqDkRPQ8DIuiOgMlO-yJlolLZz3h9N-r7W5Nn9S84KnFOm0/exec?spreadsheetId="+SPREAD_SHEET_ID+"&sheet=";
    String Script_Nombre="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzTgXJDycfFZ2beJk-I-F0GQuQp06_EORIhEhsVuMoygp4pU2vx/exec";
    String Table_Miguel="MIGUEL";
    String Table_Pep="Pep";
    RequestQueue mQueue;
    JsonArrayRequest jsonarrayrequest;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    ArrayList<String> ListaTareas;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListaTareas=new ArrayList<String>();
        JsonParse();
        View v;

        v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tareas,container,false);
        ListView tabla_tareas = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lista_tareas);
        //Acceder a la tabla de tareas

        cabeceras=new ArrayList<String>();
        cabeceras.add("Reparar Blister");
        cabeceras.add("Cambiar Motor");
        cabeceras.add("Estanteria TX");
        //String cabeceras[] = { "Reparar Blister", "Cambiar Motor", "Estanteria TX"};
        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_tareas,tabla_tareas,false);
        adaptador_tareas= new ArrayAdapter <String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ListaTareas);
        tabla_tareas.addHeaderView(header);
        tabla_tareas.setAdapter(adaptador_tareas);
        tabla_tareas.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final int posicion=position;
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                dialogo1.setTitle("TERMINAR TAREA");
                dialogo1.setMessage("Has terminado esta faena?");
                dialogo1.setCancelable(false);

                dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Terminar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int which) {
                        cabeceras.remove(posicion-1);
                        adaptador_tareas.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                dialogo1.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which) {

                    }
                });
                dialogo1.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tareas, container, false);
        return v;
    }
    private void JsonParse(){
        mQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        jsonObjectRequest= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Script_Nombre, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            //JSONArray jsonarray= new JSONArray(response.toString());
                            JSONArray jsonarray=response.getJSONArray("user");

                            for (int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject tareas_hacer=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                ListaTareas.add(tareas_hacer.getString("id"));

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

}
```

El script del Json me retorna lo siguiente (utilizo uno de pruebas sencillo):

```
{"user":[{"id":"Acabar Estanteria","name":"Dani"},{"id":"Motor","name":"Pol"}]}
```

Cuando ejecuto, no hace absolutamente nada. Me carga sin problemas la App, pero cuando le doy al Tab donde está el fragment donde quiero que me aparezca la lista, esta está vacía.  Lo que quiero hacer es que en "Tabla_Tareas" me vaya guardando cada item del Json correspondiente a "id". ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Ya estoy muy perdido y no tengo ni idea de que es lo que está pasando. Parece que no entra en el onResponse. He hecho varias pruebas y nada.

GRACIAS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que estas seteeando la lista de valor antes de recibir la respuesta:

```
 private void JsonParse(){
    mQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    jsonObjectRequest= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Script_Nombre, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        //JSONArray jsonarray= new JSONArray(response.toString());
                        JSONArray jsonarray=response.getJSONArray("user");

                        for (int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject tareas_hacer=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            ListaTareas.add(tareas_hacer.getString("id"));

                        }

                            adaptador_tareas= new ArrayAdapter <String>(getActivity(), 
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ListaTareas);
                           tabla_tareas.addHeaderView(header);
                           tabla_tareas.setAdapter(adaptador_tareas);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

Comment: El header y el adaptador lo tengo declarado en el Onview. Dónde los declaro entonces? o lo meto todo en el onview?

Comment: declaras como mierbros de la clase, osea abajo del nombre de la clase

Comment: no tira... ahora ni me aparece el header ni nada de la lista. Podrías poner como quedaría el código para ti? Gracias!